# Is this possible to prove statement for any square matrix

Tags: matrices, geometric-series

I have a statement:
$det(I + A + A^2 + ... + A^{2022}) \ge 0$, where A is a square matrix. The task is to prove it and say, is it possible for it to be equal to $0$?

I'm preparing for the math contest this spring. This problem was last year. I'm very confused with it. As I understand $I$ is identity matrix. It's geometric series of matrices generated by A. I found this formula on the Internet:
$$ S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k = (I-A)^{-1}(I-A^n) $$
So I can rewrite it:
$$ S = \sum_{k=0}^{2022}A^k = (I-A)^{-1}(I-A^{2023}) $$
But I don't know what to do next. How to prove that this greater or equal $0$? Maybe I do something wrong or this problem should be solved by using another formula or method? Please explain how to solve it. I appreciate all hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $A$ is meant to be a real matrix, otherwise the statement is not true at all.

Hint:
Let $f(x) = 1+x+\ldots+x^{2022}$.  If $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ (counting multiplicities), then $\det(f(A)) = \prod_j f(\lambda_j)$.
What can you say about $f(\lambda_j)$ if $\lambda_j$ is real?  What about
$f(\lambda_j) f(\overline{\lambda_j})$ if $\lambda_j$ is not real?

Further hint: the fact that $f(x) = (x^{2023}-1)/(x-1)$ may be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question. As I understand, f(x) always greater than 0, so f(λj) also greater than 0. It means that determinant will also be greater than 0. But if λj is not real, then it can be less than 0. I understand correctly?

Comment: $f(x) > 0$ for real $x$.  For non-real eigenvalues $\lambda$, the complex conjugate $\overline{\lambda}$ is also an eigenvalue (with the same algebraic multiplicity), and $f(\lambda) f(\overline{\lambda}) = f(\lambda) \overline{f(\lambda)} = |f(\lambda)|^2 \ge 0$. So it can't be negative, but it will be $0$ if an eigenvalue of $A$ happens to be a (complex) root of $f$.